# Serilog Logger - Requested value 'True' was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog

I'm getting this error when calling calling `Serilog.Log.Logger()`:

This is .NET Core 2.1

> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'True' was not found.

My `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    private static IConfiguration Configuration => new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile(
            $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
            true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
        
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration).CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Web hosting is starting up.");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "A fatal exception has forced unexpected host termination.");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.Information("Web hosting is shutting down.");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "Warning"
            }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Elasticsearch",
            "Args": {
                "nodeUris": "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com",
                "indexFormat": "log-XXXXXXXXXX-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
                "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
                "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
        "FromLogContext",
        "WithMachineName",
        "WithEnvironmentUserName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "{myappname}"
    }
}
```

Here are the packages used installed on in this project (excuse the screenshot)

```
C:\repos\myapp\myapp>dotnet list package
Project 'myapp' has the following package references
[netcoreapp2.1]: 
Top-level Package                                         Requested   Resolved
> BuildBundlerMinifier                                    3.2.435     3.2.435
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App                          (A)   [2.1.1, )   2.1.1
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design                       2.1.2       2.1.2
> Microsoft.NETCore.App                             (A)   [2.1.0, )   2.1.0
> Serilog.AspNetCore                                      3.2.0       3.2.0
> Serilog.Enrichers.Environment                           2.1.3       2.1.3
> Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch                             8.0.1       8.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": true
> ```

The issue relates the `autoRegisterTemplateVersion` argument in the appsettings.json file.

From the [Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch JSON appsettings.json configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch#json-appsettingsjson-configuration), we can see the `autoRegisterTemplateVersion` argument should be a string type:

[image]

After changing the `autoRegisterTemplateVersion` argument value from `true` to `"ESv2"`, the issue disappears.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!